# How to select multiple svg elements using d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, selection, multipleselection

How do I select multiple SVG elements using the right mouse button and the CRTL key?

What I would like is similar to [this example](https://gist.github.com/jo/4068610) I found (the part on the right).
It is possible to select only one element or, by holding down the CTRL key, several elements.

I looked at the code and I can't reproduce it in my case.

**My case:**
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/84yho7uw/1/)

I have more circles I wish I could select.
I would like that when the user selects a circle, the `id` of the chosen circle is printed.
When the user has finished selecting what he wants, and he presses the `Finish` button, then I would like the list of selected items to be printed.

Can this be done? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

---

## UPDATE

I changed the code of @Shashank, now it works. I hope it can be useful to someone :)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="circles">
        <svg>
            <circle id="first" cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="purple" />
            <circle id="second" cx="60" cy="60" r="5" fill="red" />
            <circle id="third" cx="110" cy="110" r="15" fill="orange" />
            <circle id="fourth" cx="90" cy="50" r="7" fill="yellow" />
        </svg>
    </div>

  <button type="button" id="finalSelection">Finish</button>

  <span style="display:block;margin-top: 10px;">Selected IDs: <span class="values"></span></span>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var selectedIds = [];

d3.selectAll('#circles svg circle').on('click', function() {
    // fetch ID
    var id = d3.select(this).attr('id');

    // toggle "clicked" class and push/splice id within the selectedIds array accordingly based on event.metaKey (CTRL)
    if(d3.select(this).classed('clicked')) { // classed add/remove a CSS class from the selection
        d3.select(this).classed('clicked', false).style('stroke', null);
        selectedIds.splice(selectedIds.indexOf(id), 1); // the splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s)
    } 
    else { // if an item has never been selected
        if(selectedIds.length) { // if the array selectedIds is not empty
            if(d3.event.ctrlKey) { // if CTRL is pressed
                d3.select(this).classed('clicked', true).style('stroke', 'blue');
                selectedIds.push(id); 
            }
            else { // *** OK *** if the item I'm selecting has never been selected and before I had already selected other elements
                // I "remove" all those already selected
                d3.selectAll(".clicked").classed('clicked', false).style('stroke', null);
                selectedIds = [];
                // I consider selected the one actually selected
                d3.select(this).classed('clicked', true).style('stroke', 'blue');
                selectedIds.push(id); 
            }
        } 
        else { // if the array selectedIds is empty
            d3.select(this).classed('clicked', true).style('stroke', 'blue');
            selectedIds.push(id);
        }
    }

    $('span.values').html(selectedIds.join(', '));
});

$('button#finalSelection').click(function() {
    $('span.values').html(selectedIds.join(', '));
    console.log("compare!")
});
```

**style.css**

```
span.values {
  color: #428bca;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/booLb1wn/) with the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure it can done. Are you sure it should be a **right mouse button click** and CTRL?

Here's a snippet doing that:

```js
var selectedIds = [];

d3.selectAll('#circles svg circle').on('contextmenu', function() {
 // prevent default right click functionality
 d3.event.preventDefault();
  
  // fetch ID
 var id = d3.select(this).attr('id');
  
  // toggle "clicked" class and push/splice id within the selectedIds array accordingly based on event.ctrlKey (CTRL)
 if(d3.select(this).classed('clicked')) {
   if(selectedIds.length > 1) {
     if(d3.event.ctrlKey) {
     d3.select(this).classed('clicked', false).style('stroke', null);
      selectedIds.splice(selectedIds.indexOf(id), 1);
      }
    } else {
    d3.select(this).classed('clicked', false).style('stroke', null);
     selectedIds.splice(selectedIds.indexOf(id), 1);    
    }  
  } else {
   if(selectedIds.length) {
     if(d3.event.ctrlKey) {
     d3.select(this).classed('clicked', true).style('stroke', '#000');
      selectedIds.push(id); 
      }
    } else {
    d3.select(this).classed('clicked', true).style('stroke', '#000');
     selectedIds.push(id);
    }
  }
  
  $('span.values').html(selectedIds.join(', '));
});

 $('button#finalSelection').click(function() {
     $('span.values').html(selectedIds.join(', '));
  });
```

```css
span.values {
  color: #428bca;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <div id="circles">
  <svg>
   <circle id="first" cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="purple" />
   <circle id="second" cx="60" cy="60" r="5" fill="red" />
   <circle id="third" cx="110" cy="110" r="15" fill="orange" />
   <circle id="fourth" cx="90" cy="50" r="7" fill="yellow" />
  </svg>
 </div>
  
  <button type="button" id="finalSelection">Finish</button>
  
  <span style="display:block;margin-top: 10px;">Selected IDs: <span class="values"></span></span>
</body>

</html>
```

I've added comments within the snippet but let me tell you how it works:

1. Use `d3.select().on('contextmenu', function())` for mouse right click event listeners.
2. `preventDefault()` has to be called to prevent the default functionality of a mouse right button click i.e. hide the default contextmenu.
3. `selectedIds` is an array that keeps a track of clicked IDs.
4. `d3.event.ctrlKey` is the **key** here -- which checks for CTRL press.
5. Added simple HTML to print the IDs. I think you can take it from here.

Also, just in case you change your mind to make it a **left mouse click + CTRL**, change the `contextmenu` to `click` and take out the call to `preventDefault()`.

Let me know if you have any questions. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the help but your code doesn't work. It allows you to select only one circle, the CRTL key doesn't work and not even the button.
I tried both using the left mouse button (thus changing `contextmenu` in `click` and deleting `preventDefault()`) or with the right button.

Comment: Oops my bad, I'm sorry. I'm so used to using the Command Key on the Mac that I coded it accordingly. I've changed the code from `d3.event.metaKey` to `d3.event.ctrlKey`. Check out the latest edit and let me know. Thanks.